# Usage of Philanthropist Flare as Schizoid

Tags: cosmic-encounter

Suppose I'm playing as Schizoid. I have the power to alter reality, so I choose one of the six new cards to be the new win condition. That card is face down.

Then suppose I use Philanthropist Flare:

> Send one of your ships to the warp to lend your power to another player for the duration of the encounter. Until the end of the encounter, that player is considered to have your power instead of his or her own. You may not use your power while it is loaned out. The player may not refuse the loan of your power.

Would the player I use this on get to look at the win condition card?

Comment: I would say yes, since "On each challenge, the offensive player may ask you a "yes" or "no" question about the win. You must answer truthfully, aloud." You cannot answer truthfully if you don't know the answer.

Comment: @user1873 That is the rule for the Eon version of Cosmic Encounter, and given the mention of the Flare, I'd guess the OP is asking about the FFG version.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start by saying that there won't be an explicit answer to this question. Cosmic Encounter is about interactions, and given the number of aliens with different powers, sometimes you just have to make it up as you go and use some logic to come to the best conclusion. I think this is probably one of those situations.

My interpretation would be **when you play the Philanthropist Flare as the Schizoid, the player you lend your power to can look at the win condition.** The most logical reasoning for this is presented by dorakeen in a different answer: the player with the Schizoid power "is responsible to announce when any player(s) have fulfilled the winning conditions". When you use the Philanthropist Flare, you no longer have your power and as such cannot declare a win condition met. The person who is now the Schizoid, even temporarily, has that job.

Additionally, there's nothing on the Schizoid card that says you can't show the alternate win condition to other players. If something in the game would cause that card to be revealed to another player or players for some reason, nothing is there to stop that event. The lack of specification about whether other players could see that card leads me to believe that it could be shown.

Having said that, if you and your game group feel that the answer is actually no, there's nothing in the rules to contradict you. Remember the game is about interactions, so do what makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes because he is responsible to announce when any player(s) have fulfilled the winning conditions now. So he has to know what the winning conditions are.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, so I would suppose you wouldn't do it.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up? Why wouldn't the temporary holder of Schizoid be allowed to pick a new victory condition, as opposed to being given the victory condition that the Schizoid player picked?